# Default content in facelets template with empty ui:define

Tags: templates, jsf, facelets, template-engine

Is it valid to expect that facelets template will use a default content in page which use the template but uses an empty `ui:define`?

template:

```
<ui:insert name="header">
    default content here <!-- is it valid default content? -->
</ui:insert>
```

page which implements the template:

```
<ui:define name="header">
   <!--nothing in page defined here but expecting that default content from template will be substituted in place-->
</ui:define>
```

The default content is not shown though in this case (the comment is not there in the real page)

Comment: Did you try? What was the result? Then you know if the expectations are valid or not

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, I did . It does not work but maybe it's because I miss something... The idea is using a default content from template if nothing defined in `define` section.

Comment: It works as you define it... There IS a `<ui:define name="header">...</ui:define>, so there is something defined... That it does not contain anything does not mean it displays the default content. Remove the define and the default content is shown. As is according to the specs

Comment: @Kukeltje ya, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it will not show the default content in this case, it works as you defined it (pun intended)...

There **is** a `<ui:define name="header">...</ui:define>`, so there is something defined. That it does not contain anything does not mean it will display the default content. Remove the define and the default content is shown. As is according to the specs afaik.